# Regex pattern substitution error

Tags: python, regex, replace

I am trying to write some python code that will strip mailing address information from file names. The code I have has been taken from another question on this site. It seems to be working but I keep getting key errors in the last line.
The job class's variables are strings containing details about the job.
Early stages at the moment.

```
fileName = '73C Example St, Suburbia.txt'

rep = {
    job.street  :'',
    job.suburb  :'',
    job.town    :'',
    job.state   :'',
    job.num     :'',
    ' street'   :'',
    ' road'     :'',
    ' lane'     :'',
    ' place'    :'',
    ' court'    :'',
    ' drive'    :'',
    ' rd,'      :'',
    ' st,'      :'',
    ' pl,'      :'',
    ' cct,'     :'',
    ' ct,'      :''
    }

rep = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in rep.iteritems())
pattern = re.compile("|".join(rep.keys()), re.IGNORECASE)
fileName = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], fileName)
```

Error is:

```
fileName = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], fileName)
KeyError: '73c'
```

I don't understand why this key would fail.

As per request:

```
self.num = '73C'
self.street = 'Example'
self.suburb ='Suburbia'
self.town = 'Darwin'
self.state = 'NT'
```

Comment: Can you show the `job` object?

Comment: Sure, though it is very simple. Fields are populated from a spreadsheet.

Comment: What you have shown is the `Job` class. But we need to see the `job` object.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I can't show the exact address in the database for confidentiality reasons. But here is an example matching the case exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is case-insensitive but dict lookup is not. Looks like `"73C"` is a key in `rep`, which makes the regex match `"73c"`, but `rep["73c"]` is a `KeyError`.

Try

```
rep = dict((re.escape(k.lower()), v) for k, v in rep.iteritems())
pattern = re.compile("|".join(rep.keys()), re.IGNORECASE)
fileName = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0).lower())], fileName)
```

Comment: +1; I couldn't reproduce the error with a mock object, but I was using the 'correct' cases.

Comment: Thank you very much Janne, I'll test this as soon as I am back at work tomorrow. So obvious, as the answers always are.